# qt installation on Linux

Tags: linux, qt

I have a project that has the following line in its installation script

```
/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin/moc ../gui/gui.h -o ../gui/moc_GUI.cpp
g++ -c -I ../db -I ../placer -I ../gr -I ../gui -I /usr/lib/qt-3.3/include ../gui/*.cpp
```

I have no such path `/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin/moc` and after trying all QT installation guides I failed to bring the path or find a similar directory in installations. What exactly do I need to install?

Answer (score 0):

look at bin/ of your Qt installation (maybe on /opt/Qt/) and try to find qt binary tools such as moc, uic, qrc ... and replace the paths in you your installation scripts, or make symbolic links from your installed qt location to path's required by your installation scripts.